# Query string right after base url in htaccess

Tags: string, .htaccess

I'm currently trying to redirect every url containing query string **k**

Here is the desired result:

From: http://www.example.com/?k=test

Need: http://www.example.com/

Its working well for any directories/subdirectories but not on the base url. It also seems to work on different htaccess tester online for base url but not on the server!

**Here is the htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine on

rewritecond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
rewritecond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f 
RewriteRule (.*) - [S=12] 

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^k=(.*)$
RewriteRule (.*)?$ $1? [R=301,L]
```

Thank you

Comment: Which apache version are you using?

Comment: Apache/2.2.10 on one website and  Apache/2.2.31 on the other thank you

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /\?k
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}? [NC,L,R]
```

Same as your orignal code but I used %{THE_REQUEST} variable to manipulate the Query string.

Clear your browser's cache before testing this.

Comment: I tested it and it didn't work. Cleared cache and tested it on different browsers.

Comment: @Vincent do you have any other rules in htaccess?

Comment: @Vincent I think your first rewriting rule is conflicting with this. Try reordering them, keep my rules at the top of your other rules.